# How to make background image not resizable in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
body {
    background: url('../../asset/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This is my code for an background image. I want the image to be not resizable when I am resizing the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `background-size:cover;`. With that CSS you're telling the browser you want the background image to expand to cover the whole background area.

If you want the background image centered and not resized, just do this:

```
body {
    background: url('../../asset/background.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}
```

You can position the background in any manner you like, [here are more options](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp).

Comment: I want the background image to expand and cover the whole background area. But I don't want the image to be resizing when I am resizing the browser

Comment: background: url('../../asset/background.jpg') no-repeat center center;
 background-size: 100% 100%;I solved it by putting the above code under an div tag.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the background size:

```
background-size: 100px 100px;
```

Comment: This is the only good answer, only if you specify a fixed width or height it adapts to it, The answer with center center also rescales if the browser window get's smaller

Answer (score -1):

Setting the `background-size` to `cover` occupies the space of the div. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover).

Remove the `background-size` property and it will work fine.